# Prove the following series converges and has the sum indicated using telescoping: $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2}{3^{n-1}}=3$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

I'm trying to compute the following limit for convergence using the telescoping property, however, I'm having difficulties simplifying the equation so the property can be used:

The following is the telescoping series:
$\sum^{n}_{k=1}(b_k-b_{k+1}) = b_1-b_{n+1}$

The series I'm trying to telescope:
$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2}{3^{n-1}}=3$

I have tried:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^{n-1}} \implies \frac{6}{3^n} = \frac{9}{3^n}-3^{n-1}$

When $n = 1$ then we get $\frac{9}{3^1}=3$?

Comment: Your series is a geometric series.

Comment: @MarkViola I had thought that it might have been a geometric series! Although, I don't know where to begin. Care to throw me a bone?

Comment: So... $\frac{2}{3^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{3^n}-\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}$.  For example $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9}=\frac{2}{9}$.  Can you continue?

Comment: $3^0=1$ - omitted in your approach for $n=1$..

Comment: As for using geometric series, it should be well known that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$ as well as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k = \frac{x}{1-x}$

Comment: @JMoravitz You have lost me with the geometric series explanation. I've tried to think about how to approach this, though I'm unsure with how I can use the geometric series. Do I do something like $\frac{1}{3^n} \implies \frac{1}{x^k} = \frac{1-x}{x}$?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2}{3^{n-1}} = 2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^n = 2\cdot \dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=2\cdot\dfrac{1}{\frac{2}{3}}=3$

Comment: As for telescoping,  $(3-1)+(1-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9})+(\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{27})+\dots$  Remember that not every series telescopes, and it wasn't immediately obvious that this series telescoped either, so most people would not have tried to find a way to describe it as a telescoping series and would have instead taken the far more obvious approach of describing as a geometric series.

Comment: @JMoravitz I need to brush up on my understanding of geometric series, although you have made it perfectly clear to me! I'm happy to accept your comments as an answer.